# Unresolved reference sqrt() Kotlin

Tags: java, math, reference, kotlin

I want to use :  ([link](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/sqrt.html))

```
fun sqrt(x: Double): Double
```

which is a basic math function in my kotlin version :

> kotlinc-jvm 1.2.0 (JRE 1.8.0_151-b12)

Actually my code is :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){ 
    println(doSqrt("16"));
}

fun doSqrt(num: String) : String{
    var number: Int = num.toInt();
    var nb: Double = number.toDouble();
    var result: Double = sqrt(nb);
    return (result.toString())
}
```

but when I compile with

> kotlinc test.kt -include-runtime -d test.jar

Result is :

```
test.kt:10:26: error: unresolved reference: sqrt
     var result: Double = sqrt(nb);
```

I try to import

> kotlin.Math

It doesn't work I also try to import

> kotlin.*

Same problem...

Which way to use the sqrt function in Kotlin ?

Comment: `import kotlin.math.sqrt`

Comment: Why did import kotlin.* doesn't work ?

Comment: Because the star notation is not recursive, just like in Java.

Comment: What duffymo is saying is that if you want to use `*` you should `import kotlin.math.*` rather than `import kotlin.*`

Comment: Also, you can (and should) remove those semicolons. They have no effect.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use the eval() function. How can I know which package to import ?

Comment: @BaptisteMarcos Which IDE are you using? Maybe you should consider using an IDE such as [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), where you can configure auto import to avoid doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can import `kotlin.math.pow`

it works like this

```
Double.pow(x)
```

so, 2 squared would be (2.0).pow(2)
the square root of 4 would be (4.0).pow(0.5)